# Почему на сайте большинство вопросов от новичков. Так было запланировано?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, репутация

Изначально я пришел на SO для получения ответов на интересующие меня вопросы. То есть я заваливал форум тупыми вопросами (думал, честно говоря, что меня пульнут отсюда).

Наверное, это определенного вида эволюция, когда пользователь сначала дорастает до какого-то уровня репутации и потом начинает отвечать на вопросы. Вероятнее всего есть какая-то закономерность. Например, я перестал бояться выражать свое мнение, и как результат начал постепенно отвечать на вопросы. Вопросы разные, сложные и не очень, но я стал заходить на сайт не для того, чтобы задавать вопросы, а для того, чтобы отвечать на них. Вначале, конечно, пришлось пару раз удалить ответы, но постепенно мои ответы становились более осмысленными. Это только мое виденье ситуации))

Но что для меня кажется странным — так это большое количество вопросов от новеньких участников, не тех у кого 100-500 баллов, а те кто вообще ничего не имеет, 1 - 100. Либо я раньше не замечал, либо это какой-то сайтовый механизм.

Растолкуйте мне, пожалуйста, что происходит.

Comment: Вы наблюдаете круговорот новичков и репутации в SO хД)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Большинство участников SO имеют именно репутацию в районе единицы. То есть, человек приходит, задаёт вопрос, получает ответ и больше его тут никто не видит. В более редких случаях люди приходят задавать вопросы дальше. Ну и еще реже, когда начинают отвечать и посещать сайт на регулярной основе. Собственно то же самое вы описываете в первой части своего повествования. Так что ничего удивительного в этом нет.

Comment: Дополню, что скорее всего "человек приходит, задаёт вопрос, получает ответ и уходит", до следующего раза, когда ему проще создать новый аккаунт, чем вспомнить старый.

Comment: @Kromster при таком раскладе получается, что он использует **разные** адреса Email.

Comment: Тут карты в руки администрации - анализировали ли они емейлы новичков или нет. Лично я для всяких неважных сайтов использую т.н. 10-minute mail.

Comment: @Kromster, такие адреса чаще всего легко определить. Например, вряд ли у кого-то email dwfegrfwcng@kllm.com . А вот john-connor@gmail.com **может быть** вполне реальным.

Comment: @VadSim может быть. Однако фильтровать адреса по белым спискам нереально, а черные слишком часто обновлять придется

Comment: Часть до символа @ нам поможет. Вряд ли кто-то запомнит логин dwfegrfwcng. А вот john-connor – легко. Хотя разные люди бывают.

Comment: Всё к тому, что мы можем отфильтровать ≈70% временных email.

Comment: `когда начинают отвечать и посещать сайт на регулярной основе` - я из этой категории ^_^